# test tablet mobile webapp

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-website, tablet

i'm developing a webapp for a 10" android tablet, what would you say is the best/fastest way to see how the app will lokk like on such a screen ? maybe in the Emulator, but how to set it up and maybe it's to slow for me to make quick refreshs ? isn't there a a posibilty to have just the android browser for windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest and most accurate way will always be a real device.

Apart from that you could always use the Android emulator to simulate different screen sizes and resolutions (this is meant for android app development but no reason why you can't use it for mobile web development).

The Android emulator is part of the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), you would just need to use AVD manager to create a new virtual device.

Comment: Android SDK also has a bunch of "plugins" that allow you create an emulator targeted only at one particular device (Motorola Bionic, for example).